# remove particular option from second from first in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have two Dropdown list  and both have same option value , but i want that if user select any option from first dropdown list , than that value automatically remove from second Dropdown list and disble second dropdown list until user not selected first dropdown list.
this is i want in javaScript or jQuery.
thanks in advanced.

Comment: What have you tried? We can't write the code for you but can help if you get stuck!

Answer (score 1):

What about this [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/tgqee2d8/3/):

**HTML**

```
<select id='main'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id='depend'>
  <option value="bmw">bmw</option>
  <option value="honda">honda</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#main").change(function(){
    var val = this.value;    
    var myList = $('#depend option').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();

    if(myList.indexOf(val) != -1)    
      $('#depend option[value='+val+']').remove();               
})
```

Comment: i just used  $("[id^=2ndapprover] option[value='"+value+"']").remove();